# LiveAPI() to control loop

Tags: ableton-live

I am trying to disable looping via `LiveAPI()` calls in Ableton Live 10 and Max 4 Live...

[image]

How do I trigger the Loop button pictured here?

I have tried various combinations of the `path`, via the nodeJS library `max4node`

https://github.com/alpacaaa/max4node

```
max.set({
    path: 'live_set tracks 1 clip_slots 0 clip looping',
    property: 'bool',
    value: false
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
max.set({
    path: 'live_set tracks 1 clip_slots 0 clip',
    property: 'looping',
    value: false
});
```